# Can jQuery be used to extract data from HTML pages?

Tags: android, jquery, json, parsing, jsoup

I stumbled across jQuery while during a search for my project that involves parsing and extracting content from HTML pages. Wondering if I could use jQuery for this purpose. If so can someone share with me some examples or share links to tutorials?

For instance I would like to parse the top questions on Stackoverflow and display it to the user as a mobile app, mostly Android.

If jQuery is not possible, what are the alternatives ? (The easiest/efficient method of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, jQuery is not the right tool for scraping!

Javascript generally has a same origin policy where you don't have access to cross domain sites. This means you can access files on your own server within the same domain, but not other sites like Stack Overflow, with the exception of sites that have enabled CORS or is using JSONP etc.

Any serverside language, like PHP, RoR, Python, C# etc can be used, whatever you choose is up to you.

Comment: I really liked jQuery because you can just make one mobile web app that works for many different platforms. So are you sure there is absolutely no way of parsing HTML pages using jQuery?

Comment: What other similar languages like jQuery for Mobile Development that support parsing from other HTML pages?

Comment: You can still use jQuery for your mobile app or whatever, but you can't get the contents of cross domain pages with javascript, you'll have to use the serverside, and as that is something that would run on the server, it will work anywhere, browsers or devices aren't an issue with serverside code like that.